# how to set a widget place according to screen size flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a widget and I want it to have a specific space from the edge of the screen, according to screen size. I have already tried `MediaQuery` but that is not helpful. Because I want to have a space according to resolution. Here is what I have tried :

```
MediaQuery.of(context).size.width - 50,
```

And here is what I'm trying to do

[image]

How I'm gonna do that?

Comment: Try multiple of `MediaQuery` like `MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.1`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can store width of screen to field to use it easily anywhere. And to have dynamic spaces, you can doing like [Hamza](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12297382/hamza) says in comments:

```
double mWidth;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    mWidth= MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        width: mWidth,
        margin: EdgeInsets.all(mWidth * 0.01),
       ),
    );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As @Hamza mentioned, you can use a percentage to get a relative size. There is a blog in [here](https://medium.com/tagmalogic/widgets-sizes-relative-to-screen-size-in-flutter-using-mediaquery-3f283afc64d6) about this issue.

```
    Container(
        height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.01, // like this.
     );
```